# Single AWS IOT rule for all thing shadow updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

Hi I am new to AWS IOT rules and I have a use case where I need to process all the successful updates to multiple thing shadows in a lambda. The rule triggers the lambda.

Currently my iot rule is something like this:

`SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/testThing/shadow/update/accepted'`

But instead of 'testThing' i want to use something like

`SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/#/shadow/update/accepted'`

which will trigger the same lambda for any thing shadow update.

But I am unable to come up with such a rule. Currently I am creating multiple rules(one for each shadow) which I don't think is the right thing to do.

I might use something like

`SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/#'`

which will give lot of unwanted data and unwanted triggers, I am trying to avoid doing such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that I need to use + instead of *,#

`SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'`